# Errno 1782 on MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I have 3 servers configured with multi-source replication ([my replication topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jT05.jpg)). It worked fine for 2 weeks, but now I getting error on a slave (server C at image):

> Error executing row event: '@@SESSION.GTID_NEXT cannot be set to ANONYMOUS when @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON.'

I tried to set GTID_NEXT/GTID_PURGED but it not worked.
Is possible to up this slave without reseting the master of server A (I reseted the master of server C)?
When I created the replication I setted AUTO_POSITION to 0, then if I get 
the slave to run again the server C will read the missing log.

The version of MySQL is 5.7.17.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to my.cnf

> slave-skip-errors = 1782